# Sizing Issue on responsive nav Foundation 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation 5 as my front-end framework and am having an issue with the responsive dropdown menu on click not staying at 100% screen width.

When not clicked the navbar appears like this:

[image]

On Button click the menu looks like this:

[image]

It comes off the sides and top of the screen by about 30 px on each side of the clicked menu box.

my nav bar code looks like this:

```
<!-- Start - TopBar -->
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div class="fixed">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
      <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">

        </li>
         <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
      </ul>

      <section class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right">
          <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#">Admin Functions</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><%= link_to "My Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path(@user) %></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#"><%= current_user.f_name %> <%= current_user.l_name %></a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><%= link_to "My Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path(@user) %></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Left Nav Section -->
        <ul class="left">
          <li><%= link_to "Dashboard", culverts_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<!-- End - TopBar -->
```

I am unsure of how to correct this, I have asked on the foundation forums, to no avail.

Please ask if you require any further information.

Thanks.

Comment: did you checked via inspect element when click on `navbar`

Comment: yes there are no errors appearing

Comment: no when clicking on navbar why the width of navbar reduce?

Comment: im trying to figure that out

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/two6v954/ use this fiddle

Comment: that actually made it worse lol..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117156/discussion-between-uzaif-and-shawn-wilson).

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the rails generated scaffold.scss I forgot to exclude it from the generation and it was conflicting with my code.

The problem has been resolved.